# Replace value in xml file

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to replace password value with in a xml file with a new value stored in MyFile, can someone please let me know the ways through achieve this.Thanks

MyFile=test123

```
<Resource accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" auth="Container" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" factory="com..tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password="myPassword"/>
```

Below error shown after executing the below command, please advise.

```
 xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl --inplace \ --update '//Resource/@password' --value "testingfile" \ /apps/META-INF/context.xml
```

**failed to load external entity " --update"**

```
 xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl --inplace --update '//Resource/@password' --value 'testingfile' /apps/META-INF/context.xml
```

/apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: AttValue: " or ' expected
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password=
^
/apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: attributes construct error
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password=
^
/apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: Couldn't find end of Start Tag Resource line 26
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password=
^

Comment: 1. valid xml cannot have a space after the opening `<`; 2. you can't use curly quotes, stick to plain double quotes.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, fix your XML

```
$ cat file.xml
<resources password="password"/>
```

Next, don't edit XML with anything except a real XML parser.
[xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is a handy one.

```sh
$ cat MyFile
test123
$ xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl --inplace \
                --update '//resources/@password' --value "$(cat MyFile)" \
                file.xml
$ cat file.xml
<resources password="test123"/>
```

To change the password for a *particular* resource, such as one with a specific value of the "name" attribute:

```
... --update '//resources[@name = "jdbc/server"]/@password' ...
```

Comment: Unable to execute, bash: xmlstarlet: command not found

Comment: @Kumar Install it, then.

Comment: It's as eaasy as `sudo apt install xmlstarlet` or `brew install xmlstarlet` or ... (adjust for your OS)

Comment: after executing the above command I see  failed to load external entity " --update", please see updated executed command.Thanks.

Comment: The backslashes are for line continuations. If you're going to put the command all on line line, remove those backslashes. What you have with `\ --update` is the same as `" --update"` and the literal leading space prevents xmlstarlet from seeing the update option.

Comment: xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl --inplace --update '//Resource/@password' --value 'testingfile' /apps/META-INF/context.xml
/apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: AttValue: " or ' expected
 maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password=

Comment: /apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: attributes construct error maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/server" password= ^ /apps/META-INF/context.xml:26.119: Couldn't find end of Start Tag Resource line 26

Comment: Thank you Glenn, its working now, one quick question how do I change value only in one place in xml file where in my xml file we have more than 3 Resource name available and each resource tag has the password="", how do I search and apply the value only on that particular resource?

Comment: <Resource name="jdbc/test1"/> and  <Resource name="jdbc/test2" and  <Resource name="jdbc/test3"

Comment: That's an XPath question: `--update '//Resource[@name = "jdbc/test1"]/@password' --value "$newPassword"`

Comment: I have found this page useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN